# Update sql server express edition to another edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have installed on my computer SQL Server Express Edition (2014 I guess), and I have a project who suppose to create a backup for a DB. But I found out from the internet that the Express Edition doesn't have the Maintenance Plan from the Management Folder or the SQL Server Agent. So I want to update this edition with another edition who will have all of these but I don't know why, can you help me, please? I don't want to pay for the new edition because this project is for school and then I don't know when I will use SQL Management Studio. Thank you!

PS:When I make upgrade I don't want to lose my DBs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need backups, you do not need to upgrade the edition.

You can use [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/) maintenance solution and run the commands from the Operating System Scheduled Tasks.
Here are the instructions: [How do I get started with the SQL Server Maintenance Solution on SQL Server Express?](https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html)

I use this for all my Express installs and it works fine.

Comment: Hey can you help me a little? I don't know what is the problem but after I did what says the steps and now I have to execute this: 

`SQLCMD -E -S DESKTOP-C6UF2MS\EQLEXPRESS -d TransportCompany -Q "EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @Directory = N'C:\Backup', @BackupType = 'FULL'" -b -o D:\Scoala\Master_CSC\ABD\Proiect\TrabsportCompanyDatabaseBackup.txt`      I get this error message: Incorrect syntax near 'E'. And I don't know what is it.

Comment: It appears you have a typo in the instance name `DESKTOP-C6UF2MS\EQLEXPRESS` should it be `DESKTOP-C6UF2MS\SQLEXPRESS`? Here is a sample from one of mine: `sqlcmd -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d DBA -Q "EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @Directory = N'C:\SQLBackups', @BackupType = 'FULL', @Verify = 'Y', @CleanupTime = '720', @CheckSum = 'Y', @LogToTable = 'Y'" -b -o "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\DatabaseBackupUser.txt"`